# "Canceled Future" Error: Seeking Solutions for Building CNN Models

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, data-science

What could be the possible cause of the "Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done" error when building a CNN model? I have tried several solutions, but the error persists. Any suggestions or alternative approaches to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

ERROR: Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done
The Kernel crashed while executing code in the the current cell or a previous cell. Please review the code in the cell(s) to identify a possible cause of the failure. Click here for more info. View Jupyter log for further details.

I created a new environment and thoroughly checked for any conflicts or compatibility issues with the dependencies.